# Maintaining state in Listview.Builder() of Stateful widget (a progress bar) problem

Tags: flutter

I am creating a listview using listview.builder. Each view is a card with a button on it and a progress bar (See screenshot)
[image]

Each card is a stateful widget. When you press the button, the progressbar starts a 5 second timer. When the timer is over, the object is removed from the LinkedHashMap which makes is dissapear from the screen too. This works, if only one button is pressed in the displayed list. If one button is pressed and after 2 seconds second or/and third button(s) are pressed, the animation of progress bar can be seen on all three, but as soon as a first one dissapears from the screen and the second and subsequest are re-drawn, they loose there state and they appear as if their buttons were never pressed.

What I am trying to do is, keep their states independent and keep their animations independent. When one card dissapears, the others gets shifted up/down accordingly but the progress animation to continue as it is as currently they seem to redraw themselve in unpressed/original state.

My code for my card is as follows:

```
class _DeliveryCardsViewState extends State<DeliveryCardsView> {
  double percentage = 1.0;
  bool countdownStarted = false;
  String buttonText = "CLAIM ORDER";

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0, vertical: 10.0),
      child: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0, bottom: 10.0, left: 10.0, right: 10.0),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0)),
        ),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
              children: <Widget>[
              Text('#'+widget.delivery.uID),
              GestureDetector(
                onTap: () async {
                  if (!countdownStarted) {
                    countdownStarted = true;
                    setState(() {
                      buttonText = 'UNDO';
                    });
                    int j = 100;
                    while (j > 0) {
                      await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 50)); // Duration in seconds (50/10) = 5 seconds
                      j -= 1;
                      setState(() {
                        if (countdownStarted){
                          percentage = (j / 100).toDouble();
                        } else {
                          percentage = 1.0;
                        }
                      });
                      if (!countdownStarted){
                        setState(() {
                          buttonText = 'CLAIM ORDER';
                        });
                        break;
                      }
                    }
                    //Try to claim it now
                    if (countdownStarted) tryClaimOnFirebase();
                  } else {
                    countdownStarted = false;
                  }
                },
                child: Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text(buttonText,style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
                      SizedBox(height: 5.0,),
                      LinearPercentIndicator(
                        width: 100.0,
                        lineHeight: 7.0,
                        percent: percentage,
                        backgroundColor: Colors.green,
                        progressColor: Colors.red,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: mainGrey,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5.0)),
                  ),
                )
              ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

And my Listview.builder code is as follows:

```
return Container(color: Colors.grey[350],
      child: ListView.builder(
        key: UniqueKey(),
        itemCount: deliveriesAvailable.length,
        controller: _controller,
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        reverse: false,
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemBuilder: (context,position){
          return GestureDetector(
            child: DeliveryCardsView(delivery: deliveriesAvailable.values.elementAt(position),),
            onTap: (){},
          );
    }),
    );
```

Error recording:
[image]

Comment: How about declaring the `j` as a global variable. Each time the state changes it rebuilds the view. So each field will have the initial value and not the current value. You can declare it as global field or as parameter in the constructor

Comment: Thanks. But that would solve the problem because every object has it's own 'j' counter.

Answer (score 1):

Working now.
Alright so, I think I underdtand what was happening. The entire stateful widget was getting disposed and rebuilt and as a result the 'logic' 'inside' the stateful widget was also resetting. What I did was the following:

1) Added a couple of extra variables in the 'Object'
2) When the view gets built again, it checks those variables and then 'resumes' the state it was last disposed in, and that included the the value of the progress bar counter.

Obvously for this to happen, the entire logic was taken out from onTap() and added to a new async method.

Simplessss :)